# C 2-dimensional array malloc do not reserve first line

Tags: c

I have a problem with the first line of my table

```
char **M = malloc(dim->lignes*sizeof(char));
for(i=0;i<dim->lignes;i++)
{
    M[i]=malloc(dim->colonnes*sizeof(char));
    for(j=0;j<dim->colonnes;j++)
    {
        M[i][j] = fgetc(F);
        printf(" ");
        printf("%c",M[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    fgetc(F);
}

for(i=0;i<dim->lignes;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<dim->colonnes;j++)
    {
            printf(" ");
            printf("%c",M[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The output :

```
 # # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # #
 #         #     #
 #   # #         #
 #               #
 #               #
 #               #
 #             # #
 #           # # #
 # # # # # # # # #

 P  Õ   h  Õ   Ç
 # # # # # # # # #
 #         #     #
 #   # #         #
 #               #
 #               #
 #               #
 #             # #
 #           # # #
 # # # # # # # # #
```

I don't understand why the first print is correct and not the second.

Comment: There is no 2D array in your snippet and nothing which can point to one. If you want a 2D array, use one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char **M = malloc(dim->lignes*sizeof(char));
```

That should read as

```
char **M = malloc(dim->lignes*sizeof(char *));
```

It would have been valid if it was like this, this is hypothetical example,

```
char *M = malloc(dim->lignes*sizeof(char));
```

Notice the difference there, with the `sizeof`.

For a single pointer, use `sizeof` type

For a double pointer, use `sizeof` * type and so on.

Comment: or use `sizeof *p` in all cases (where p is the variable being assigned to)

Answer (score 3):

As well stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41309172/2410359), the following is incorrect.

```
char **M = malloc(dim->lignes*sizeof(char));  // wrong with `sizeof(char)`
```

Rather than `sizeof(char*)`, use `sizeof *the_pointer_variable`.  This is less like to code wrong, It is easier to review and maintain.  No need to change the code used in the `malloc()` argument as the type changes.

```
// OK
char **M = malloc(dim->lignes*sizeof(char*));
// Better
char **M = malloc(dim->lignes * sizeof *M);
// Best
char **M = malloc(sizeof *M * dim->lignes);
```

The last, using `sizeof` first,  has the advantage with more complex calculations.  The first one below's math is done with at least `size_t` math.  The 2nd begins it's math with whatever type `rows * columns` are.  Should that be `int * int`, overflow is possible that might not occur with `size_t` math.

```
M = malloc(sizeof *M * rows * columns);
M = malloc(rows * columns * sizeof *M);  // Overflow with rows * columns?
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running into problems because you allocate space for `char`s, which are 1 byte, when you need to allocate space for pointers to `char`, which are larger (8 bytes on my system):

```
char **M = malloc(dim->lignes*sizeof(char));
```

You can fix this by changing the above line to:

```
char **M = malloc(dim->lignes*sizeof(char *));
```

But, there are some common C idioms that help you avoid such mistakes. `M` is a pointer to a pointer to `char`, so you want to allocate storage for pointers to `char`. But `*M` is of type `(char *)`, so you can write:

```
char **M = malloc(dim->lignes*sizeof(*M));
```

You can always use this pattern, which frees you from explicitly specifying the type in the right-hand side of the statement. As an added bonus, if you ever change the type of `M` (to `(int **)`, for example), then the right hand side is still valid, so this idiom is more robust than the explicit statement of the type.

Further in your code, you have:

```
M[i]=malloc(dim->colonnes*sizeof(char));
```

But, in C a `char` is guaranteed to be 1 byte, so `sizeof(char)` is always 1. That makes the use of the `sizeof` operator redundant here. It is considered good practice to dispense with `sizeof` in such situations:

```
M[i]=malloc(dim->colonnes);
```

This reduces clutter in the code. You may instead consider using the first idiom, which will remain valid even if the type of `M` changes:

```
M[i]=malloc(dim->colonnes*sizeof(*M[i]));
```

or perhaps:

```
M[i]=malloc(dim->colonnes*sizeof(**M));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code allocates not enough memory for `M`. Luckily, you can see the effects immediately in this special case.

The memory layout is:

```
M:     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
M[0]:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I'm assuming a 32 bit machine in the following. Then `M` is only 9 bytes large but should be 36. So when you read in line 4, the assignment to `M[3]` will be translated to `memory[M + 4*3 .. M + 4*3 + 3] = …`. The index expression is larger than the allowed 9, but the C runtime doesn't care about that. Instead it will write to the memory after the allocated `M` array, which happens to be `M[0]` your first line of characters.